# BSOD when using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: bsod, visual-studio-2008

I'm in Visual Studio trying to get work done, and get the error "VSHost.exe crashed!"  So I keep ignoring it

Then now everytime I start VS2008 and start working on a project I get the following blue screen:

```
STOP: 0x0000007E (0xC000001D, 0x80573002*, 0xF78E6840, 0xF78E653C)
```

Btw VSHost.exe was crashing in the mscorwks.dll

Comment: Seems to happen whenever I try to save now, altho its been doing this for days randomly, now it is always when I try to save.

Comment: BCCode : 1000007e     BCP1 : C0000005     BCP2 : 80572099     BCP3 : F78F2840
BCP4 : F78F253C     OSVer : 5_1_2600     SP : 3_0     Product : 256_1

Comment: This is probably unrelated to Visual Studio, I'd guess. Debugging user-mode applications doesn't grovel around in the kernel where a BSOD happens.

Comment: Nice edit save by Jennings.

Comment: @random: Was interesting in a way before too ;-)

Comment: 10 bucks says its anti virus software causing problems!
tr

Answer (score 1):

0x0000007e = SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED

The exception is  0xC000001D = Illegal instruction

I think you should have the minidump file. please try to use the debugger as described in this article and show us the result of !analyze -v

http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/29860.aspx

I'll try to follow up this post if you can provide more information.